# SwiftUI position text bottom right?

Tags: text, swiftui, vstack, hstack

Is there a better way of positioning text in SwiftUI, in the example below I am positioning the text in the bottom right corner of a ZStack, it works fine but seems long winded, am I missing a simpler way ... The orange lines are just for debugging, so that the spacers are visible in the view.

**CODE**

```
struct DisplayTwoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
            Group {
                VStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 5).background(Color.orange)
                    HStack {
                        Spacer().frame(height: 5).background(Color.orange)
                        Text("RABBITS").fontWeight(.black)
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this one (tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4)

```
struct DisplayTwoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("RABBITS").fontWeight(.black)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good option, yup I had overlooked the fact that you could align the stack.

Comment: Is there a way to align only a single object inside the contents of the ZStack?

Comment: Have same question like @Zorayr

Comment: Checkout alignmentGuides, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/alignment-and-alignment-guides. Been a bit of time, but pretty sure they worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is via the `.frame` modifier, like this:

```
ZStack {
    Text("RABBITS")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
}
```